# Search icon not working in css

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code for css:

```
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

Search Box:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
```

It is looking like this:
[image]

However, I want the search box to look like this:
[image]

Please note that I have the png file in my css folder. This example is a replication of https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_table.

Comment: You may not be referencing the image correctly. Use `https://www.w3schools.com/css/searchicon.png` instead `/css/searchicon.png`

Comment: Yeah, in your case you need to include `background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/searchicon.png');` and it should work.

Comment: I have downloaded the code on my computer. I am not running it on w3school.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your file structure I don't believe you are referencing the image like you'd want to.

Instead of:

```
background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
```

Do:

```
background-image: url('css/searchicon.png');
```

OR

```
background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/searchicon.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working correctly for me, I would just double check to see that your path is correct for image and also make sure that the css file is correctly referenced in the html

Answer (score 0):

You write: "I have the png file in my css folder."

Where is the CSS folder: At the same level as your HTML file?

Then you should write `background-image: url('css/searchicon.png');`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your image url is not correct, check it and answer me if it was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

the URL path is only related to CSS style sheet location. So depending on where your style sheet is, it is a relative path to the img.

> #### Partial URLs are interpreted relative to the source of the style sheet, not relative to the document:
>
> `BODY { background: url(yellow) }`
>
> REF: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#url

as others said, your url path is not correct, example:

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/searchicon.png);
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
```